# search in nested array doesn't work as it should work

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following function that performs the searches.

```
public static containsDeep = (text: string) => (value?: any): any => {
    if (!value) {
        return false;
    }

    const valueType = typeof value;

    if (valueType === 'string') {
        return value.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    }
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        return value.some(VimboUtils.containsDeep(text));
    }
    if (valueType === 'object') {
        return Object.values(value).some(VimboUtils.containsDeep(text));
    }
    return false;

    // tslint:disable-next-line
};


public static searchDeepInArray(array: Array<any>, text: string): any {
    if (!array || !text) {
        return null;
    }

    return array.filter(VimboUtils.containsDeep(text));
}
```

example of an array I get that I search for:

```
const value = [
{
    'config_vimbo': [
        {
            _id: '1',
            title: 'Estrutura FrontEnd - Códigos',
            path: '/apps/general-settings/frontend-structure-code',
            hidden: 'this._rolesService.hide.isNotVimbo()'
        },
        {
            _id: '2',
            title: 'Unidade de medidas CTE',
            path: '/apps/general-settings/units-measurement-cte',
            hidden: 'this._rolesService.hide.isNotVimbo()'
        }
    ]
},
{
    'Sua equipe': [
        {
            _id: '1',
            title: 'Gerencie usuários e permissões',
            path: '/apps/general-settings/user-business',
            hidden: '!this._rolesService.modules.canView("configuracao")'
        }
    ]
},
{
    'Ajustes da sua conta': [
        {
            _id: '1',
            title: 'Unidades de medidas',
            path: '/apps/general-settings/units-measurement',
            hidden: '!this._rolesService.modules.canView("configuracao")'
        }
    ]
}]
```

I call the function as follows:

```
searchDeepInArray(value,'argument');
```

what is happening that it is filtering, but only if I type the first whole word.
If I type a word that is in the middle of the sentence, it does not search correctly.
I couldn't identify where the error is.

**Edit 1**
I could reproduce the error better. What happens, when it has more than one item per position, when you type if the word has something that matches, it returns all the items of that possession where the word was found. And should return the position with only the corresponding items. see the example on this link, if I type `recebimento` comes the position with all items(2) https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnE4R.gif

**Solution found, if someone has a better solution, you can leave your comment :)**

```
public static searchDeepInArray(
        array: Array<any>,
        text: string,
        field: string
    ): any {
        if (!array || !text) {
            return null;
        }

        return array.filter(this.containsDeep(text)).map(element => {
            const idx = Object.keys(element).length
                ? Object.keys(element)[0]
                : null;

            if (!idx) {
                return element;
            }

            return Object.assign({}, element, {
                [idx]: element[idx].filter(
                    subElement =>
                        subElement[field]
                            .toLowerCase()
                            .indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) > -1
                )
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Sir, I've just tested your code and it's working perfectly. Even with words in the middle of the sentence. I tested `medidas` and it showed both `config_vimbo` and `Ajustes da sua conta`

Comment: I could reproduce the error better.
What happens, when it has more than one item per position, when you type if the word has something that matches, it returns all the items of that possession where the word was found.
And should return the position with only the corresponding items.

see the example on this link, if I type `recebimento` comes the position with all items (2)

https://i.imgur.com/Uj7MlvK.gif